# ZSH vcs_info are not updated if alias is used

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I change my branch inside my zsh sadly it is not reflecting the current branch if I use an alias, but works if I use `git checkout <branch>`.

[image]

I use oh-my-zsh and my custom theme for oh-my-zsh hosted on [github](https://github.com/lony/dotFiles/blob/master/ansible/roles/dotfiles/src/bash_zsh/.zsh_oh-my-zsh/themes/lony.zsh-theme).

My current zsh version is:

```
❯ zsh --version
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0)
```

My aliases look like the following:

```
❯ alias | grep gc
gc='git checkout'
gco='git commit'
```

My git version is:

```
❯ git --version
git version 2.21.0
```

Any ideas what could cause this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by `vcs_info` as it is not called if the last command is not containing git or svn, as checked in `steeef_preexec`.

The solution could be to just check vcs_info every-time. This is slow but solve the issue detecting even alias changes.